# (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour) it always return 0,0,0,0

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

When this program runs on raspberry pi, (x,y,w,h) always return 0,0,0,0.

```
# Load the image and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(image_file)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Add some extra padding around the image
image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, 20, 20, 20, 20, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

# threshold the image(convert it to pure black and white)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# find the contours(continuous blobs of pixels) the image
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Hack for compatibility with different OpenCV version
contours = contours[0] if imutils.is_cv3() else contours[0]

letter_image_regions = []

# Now we can loop through each of the four contours and extract the letter inside of each one
for contour in contours:
    # Get the rectagle that contains the contour
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    print(x,y,w,h)                          # it always return 0,0,0,0 for me

    # Compare the width and height of the contour to detect letters that are conjoined into one chunk
    if w / h > 1.25:
        # This contour is to wide to be a single letter!
        # Split it in half into two letter regions!
        half_width = int(w/ 2)
        letter_image_regions.append((x,y,half_width,h))
        letter_image_regions.append((x + half_width,y,half_width,h))
    else:
        #This is a normal letter by itself
        letter_image_regions.append((x,y,w,h))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJrLs.png)

I dont know what went wrong, but it works on windows.

Comment: just curious - what good is `contours = contours[0] if imutils.is_cv3() else contours[0]` - its equal to `contours = contours[0]` - could that be the culprit? Seems your rasp runs different python version then your pc

Comment: I deleted```if imutils.is_cv3() else contours[0]```,it still seems the same result

Comment: 3.7.4 is running on the pc and 3.5.3 is running one the rasp. Is this the reason?

Comment: Similar cv2 version on both systems? https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0  says it returns a list of contourswhich is a vector of points - you only handle the first detected countour. print it - see whats in it?